# batch images along path google maps street view

Tags: image, google-maps, batch-processing, google-street-view

Does anyone know how to interact with google maps street view to retrieve a batch number of images (~200) along the street view from point A to point B? I could always manually go and move along the street and "print screen." but this is time consuming. I work for city government, and we're trying to get more info on our streets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take use of the [Google Street View Image API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/intro), which gives you the ability to link to a picture of the Streetview directly. For example, 
this link:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=640x640&location=40.720032,-73.988354&fov=90&heading=235&pitch=10
links to this image:

[image]

But there are 2 problems about this `Google Street View Image API`:
1) It only support up to 640x640, no bigger image for the free account.
2) I think the ToS requires the data be publicly accessible if you are using it for free.

You can solve these by applying to the Google Maps for Work, which I might able to refer you and get discounts.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'll have to come up with a loop to batch capture images. The example link only shows 1 lat/long address being passed to the API.

Comment: yes, you need a loop. But be sure to also check the terms of services.